# Use Django Oscar Signals

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-oscar

I want to send an email to admin if an Order is placed (currently only user who have placed an order received the email). [order_paced](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.0/ref/signals.html#oscar.apps.order.signals.order_placed) Oscar Signal can work for me here.

For this I have already forked `order` app and inside this app `order_placed` function is created in `signals.py`. I have also imported signals in `config.py` but still this `order_placed` not getting fired when I am placing an order from site.

Can anyone share any example of oscar signal usage ?

Code :

`config.py`

```
from oscar.apps.order import config


class OrderConfig(config.OrderConfig):
    name = 'catalogue.order'
    
    def ready(self):
        from oscar.apps.order import signals
```

`signals.py`

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from oscar.apps.order.models import Order

@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def order_placed(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """

    print("i ma here ----------------------")
```

Comment: Pls show the relevant code of your signal handler and how/where you connect it to the signal.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I have edited my question

Comment: You would have to import your custom `signals` module in your app config's `ready`, not the one from oscar, so that the custom receiver is connected at app loading time.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  Ooooopss my bad. Thanks a lot . You can post this as answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: Might do that once I find the time =) More likely this is a duplicate of some of the more general django signal questions as it has little to do with oscar.

Comment: @schwobaseggl no problem at all

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that forking the `order` app is not necessary in this case (unless you're changing how the signal is sent). You can simply `import` the `signal` elsewhere in your existing codebase and use it as a receiver.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need signals for this, as part of the payment flow (framework) oscar provides the view: `PaymentDetailsView` which in time implements the mixin `OrderPlacementMixin`.

In such mixin you'll find the method: `handle_successful_order` which is the correct place to send the messages, and do other things being sure the order was placed.

So, do not fork `order` app, fork `checkout` app and override this method in order to do something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

class PaymentDetailView:
    # ...
    def handle_successful_order(order):
        send_mail_to_admin(settings.ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
        super(PaymentDetailView, self).handle_successful_order(order)
```

If you read the code of this method in oscar you'll see that this is indeed where oscar notify the user about the order that has been just placed.

An of course, we can not ignore the docstring which states:

> Override this view if you want to perform custom actions when an
>           order is submitted.

```
def handle_successful_order(self, order):
    """
    Handle the various steps required after an order has been successfully
    placed.

    Override this view if you want to perform custom actions when an
    order is submitted.
    """
    # Send confirmation message (normally an email)
    self.send_confirmation_message(order, self.communication_type_code)

    # Flush all session data
    self.checkout_session.flush()

    # Save order id in session so thank-you page can load it
    self.request.session['checkout_order_id'] = order.id

    response = HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    self.send_signal(self.request, response, order)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @raydel-miranda pointed out you don't need signal to send email to the admin when an order is placed by the customer.

just fork the checkout app using `./python manage.py oscar_fork_app checkout apps`

Inside the above forked checkout app create `views.py` file and override the default oscar checkout/views.py file with this code.

yourproject_name/apps/checkout/views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.contrib import messages


from django.core.mail import EmailMessage,send_mail

OscarPaymentDetailsView = get_class("checkout.views", "PaymentDetailsView")


class PaymentDetailsView(CheckCountryPreCondition, OscarPaymentDetailsView):
    
    def handle_successful_order(self, order):
        print('order creted') 
        send_mail(
        subject="New Order Needs attention",
        message='Please login the dashboard and complete the order',
        from_email=(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER),
        recipient_list=['admin_email_address_1', 'admin_email_address_2'], #x.email for x in partner_id.users.all()
        fail_silently=False,
        )
        ctx=super(PaymentDetailsView, self).handle_successful_order(order)
        #send_mail_to_admin(settings.ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
```

This may save someone else quality time trying to create signals for sending admin email when an order is placed.